# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using PXE + preseed

Tags: ubuntu, pxe

Good afternoon, trying to set up Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation with PXE-Server using a response file.

Installation is successful, but the problem is that after setting up, there are no network interfaces in the system. How can this be fixed?

I have a suspicion that it was necessary to make some magic with the help of kill-all-dhcp; netcfg, but I can not find any sensible information on how to use it.

Comment: LABEL Ubuntu 16.04
        kernel ubuntu/vmlinuz.efi
 append ip=dhcp boot=casper url=http://192.168.250.82/ubuntu/preseed.cfg netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.250.82:/srv/tftp/ubuntu/16.04 initrd=ubuntu/initrd.lz keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=ru net.ifnames=0 ip=::::lunacy::dhcp debug-ubiquity  automatic-ubiquity --

Answer (score 0):

LABEL Ubuntu 16.04
        kernel ubuntu/vmlinuz.efi
    append ip=dhcp boot=casper url=http://192.168.250.82/ubuntu/preseed.cfg netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.250.82:/srv/tftp/ubuntu/16.04 initrd=ubuntu/initrd.lz keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=ru net.ifnames=0 ip=::::lunacy::dhcp debug-ubiquity  automatic-ubiquity --